# Pass instance number to shortcode child

Tags: shortcode

I have problem passing my instance variable of shortcode `[answers]` down to it's childrens `[ans]`. Couldn't use global since that loses it's value.

Here is the code:

```
function my_answers_shortcode($params, $content = null)
{
    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    $output = "<div class='answers-wrapper'>
                    <div id='answers-{$instance}' class='answers'>";

    add_shortcode('ans', 'my_ans_shortcode');
    $output .= do_shortcode($content);

    $output .= "    </div>
                </div>";

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('answers', 'my_answers_shortcode');

function my_ans_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    global $post;
    static $ans = 0;
    $ans++;

    $output = " 
                <dl class='answer-item'>";

    $output .= "    <dd class='wp-caption-text answer-caption'>
                        <a href='?ins=".$instance."&ans=".$ans."'>".$content."</a> ".($_SESSION['page_'.($post->ID).'_ins_'.$instance.'_ans_'.$ans] == 'correct' ? "Correct!" : "")."
                    </dd>";

    $output .= "
                </dl>
                ";

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in a *class*.

Here's an example:

```
class WPSE_Answers_Counting 
{
    private $instance_answers      = 0;
    private $instance_prev_answers = 0;
    private $instance_answer       = 0;

    public function init()
    {
        add_shortcode( 'answers', [ $this, 'answers_shortcode' ] );
        add_shortcode( 'ans',     [ $this, 'answer_shortcode'  ] );         
    }

    public function answers_shortcode( $atts = [], $content = null )
    {
        // Output with [answers] counting   
        return sprintf(
            "<div class='answers-wrapper'>
                <div id='answers-%d' class='answers'>
                    %s
                </div>
            </div>",
            $this->instance_answers++,
            do_shortcode( $content )
        );
    }

    public function answer_shortcode( $atts = [], $content = null )
    {   
        // Reset single [ans] counting after each  [answers]
        if( $this->instance_prev_answers != $this->instance_answers )
            $this->instance_answer = 1;

        // Output with [ans] counting   
        $out = sprintf(  
            "<dl class='answer-item'>
                <dd class='wp-caption-text answer-caption'>
                    <a href='?ins=%d&ans=%d'>%s</a> 
                </dd>
             </dl>",
            $this->instance_answers,
            $this->instance_answer++,
            esc_html( $content )
        );

        // Update the previous [answers] instance count
        $this->instance_prev_answers = $this->instance_answers;

        return $out;
    }

} // end class
```

Create an object instance, then this shortcode mayhem:

```
[answers][ans]a1[/ans][ans]b1[/ans][ans]c1[/ans][/answers]
[answers][ans]a2[/ans][ans]b2[/ans][ans]c2[/ans][/answers]
[answers][ans]a3[/ans][ans]b3[/ans][ans]c3[/ans][/answers]
```

will output as:

```
<div class='answers-wrapper'>
    <div id='answers-0' class='answers'>
        <dl class='answer-item'>
            <dd class='wp-caption-text answer-caption'>
                <a href='?ins=1&ans=1'>a1</a> 
            </dd>
         </dl>
         <dl class='answer-item'>
            <dd class='wp-caption-text answer-caption'>
                <a href='?ins=1&ans=2'>b1</a> 
            </dd>
         </dl>
         <dl class='answer-item'>
            <dd class='wp-caption-text answer-caption'>
                <a href='?ins=1&ans=3'>c1</a> 
            </dd>
         </dl>
    </div>
</div><br />
<div class='answers-wrapper'>
    <div id='answers-1' class='answers'>
        <dl class='answer-item'>
            <dd class='wp-caption-text answer-caption'>
                <a href='?ins=2&ans=1'>a2</a> 
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class='answer-item'>
            <dd class='wp-caption-text answer-caption'>
                <a href='?ins=2&ans=2'>b2</a> 
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class='answer-item'>
            <dd class='wp-caption-text answer-caption'>
                <a href='?ins=2&ans=3'>c2</a> 
            </dd>
         </dl>
    </div>
</div><br />
<div class='answers-wrapper'>
    <div id='answers-2' class='answers'>
        <dl class='answer-item'>
            <dd class='wp-caption-text answer-caption'>
                <a href='?ins=3&ans=1'>a3</a> 
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class='answer-item'>
            <dd class='wp-caption-text answer-caption'>
                <a href='?ins=3&ans=2'>b3</a> 
            </dd>
         </dl>
         <dl class='answer-item'>
            <dd class='wp-caption-text answer-caption'>
                <a href='?ins=3&ans=3'>c3</a> 
            </dd>
         </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the (hopfully) correct instance number counting you're after.

### Update:

You'll probably want to reset the single `[ans]` counting after each `[answers]`, so I adjusted the class to support that.

Here's the *static* version:

```
add_shortcode( 'answers', 'WPSE_Answers_Counting::answers_shortcode' );
add_shortcode( 'ans',     'WPSE_Answers_Counting::answer_shortcode'  );         

class WPSE_Answers_Counting 
{
    private static $instance_answers      = 0;
    private static $instance_prev_answers = 0;
    private static $instance_answer       = 0;

    public static function answers_shortcode( $atts = [], $content = null )
    {
        return sprintf(
            "<div class='answers-wrapper'>
                <div id='answers-%d' class='answers'>
                    %s
                </div>
            </div>",
            self::$instance_answers++,
            do_shortcode( $content )
        );
    }

    public static function answer_shortcode( $atts = [], $content = null )
    {   
        // Reset single [ans] coutning
        if( self::$instance_prev_answers != self::$instance_answers )
            self::$instance_answer = 1;

        $out = sprintf(  
            "<dl class='answer-item'>
                <dd class='wp-caption-text answer-caption'>
                    <a href='?ins=%d&ans=%d'>%s</a> 
                </dd>
             </dl>",
            self::$instance_answers,
            self::$instance_answer++,
            esc_html( $content )
        );

        // Update the previous instance 
        self::$instance_prev_answers = self::$instance_answers;

        return $out;
    }

} // end class
```

Comment: Waaow... What a awesome answer! Very neat. And it works. I will now study it several times, to learn how it works. Fascinating... Thank you very much!

Comment: Great, you're welcome @PeterWesterlund